# JAVA Metodos realizados pero a la hora de ejecutar no hace nada

Tags: java

No encuentro el problema! El programa se ejecuta pero no me da valores, se queda en 0 o null, ademas en obra asignada me sale "---". Adjunto primero mi código, que luego se ejecuta en otro archivo java que esta realizado por el profesor que es el main y el ultimo código es utilidades que también lo da el profesor para que se ejecute el codigo.

LA CLASE COMPLETA TEATRO ES https://www.online-java.com/mLr4vGUgqz

El enunciado es resumido:

- El método comprarEntradas, que recibirá como parámetro el número de entradas que se quieren comprar.
- El método comprarEntrada, que no recibirá ningún parámetro y que realizará la compra de una sola entrada.

Y en el código de utilidades sale como int entradas

Mi código

```
 public void comprarEntradas (int Entradas) throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException {
   
   
   if (!nombreTeatro.contains(Obra)){
       throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada, por tanto no se pueden comprar entradas");}
       
   
   if (this.Entradas >= AFORO_MAX){
       throw new IllegalStateException ("El numero de entradas supera el aforo, no pueden aumentarse las entradas");}
   
   if (this.Entradas <= 0 ){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException ("No se pueden comprar"+ Entradas + "entradas");}
  
   this.Entradas = ++ EntradasVendidas;
   this.EntradasVendidas = ++EntradasVendidasTotales;}



public void comprarEntrada(){ comprarEntradas(1);} 
   
  //DEVOLVERENTRADAS ES LO MISMO PERO LO HE OMITIDO PARA VER MAS FACIL
   
   public void vaciarTeatro ()throws IllegalStateException {
       
       if (!nombreTeatro.contains(Obra)){
           throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada, por tanto no puede vaciarse");}
       
       if (EntradasVendidas <= 0 ){
           throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene entradas vendidas para esa obra, por tanto no puede vaciarse");}
       
       this.EntradasVendidas = --EntradasVendidasTotales;
      }
   
   public void llenarTeatro() throws IllegalStateException{
       
       if (!nombreTeatro.contains(Obra)){
           throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada, por tanto no puede llenarse");}
       
       if (EntradasVendidas > Teatro.AFORO_MAX){
           throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro ya esta completo para esa obra, por tanto no puede llenarse.");}}
```

El código main en el que corre tiene esto:

```
Utilidades.devolverEntradasTeatro(teatro1,4); //Error: No hay tantas entradas vendidas en este teatro
```

(Asi en las distintas veces)

Y el código de utilidades, es el que me dan por defecto en el ejercicio. Yo lo que tengo que hacer es en el código primero que son las que estoy haciendo yo implementar las utilidades para que vaya bien la prueba que es el main.

```
public static void comprarEntradasTeatro(Teatro miTeatro, int entradas) {
    StringBuilder consulta = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        consulta.append(cabecera(String.format("Intentando comprar %d entradas para la obra \"%s\" en el teatro \"%s\"", entradas, miTeatro.tieneObra() ? miTeatro.getObra() : "---", miTeatro.getNombreTeatro())) );
        miTeatro.comprarEntradas(entradas);
        consulta.append("Compra realizada con éxito.\n");
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        consulta.append(String.format("Error. %s\n", ex.getMessage()) );
    } finally {
        consulta.append(String.format("Número de entradas vendidas para la obra actual: %d\n", miTeatro.getEntradasVendidas()));
        consulta.append(String.format("Número de entradas vendidas totales: %d\n", Teatro.getEntradasVendidasTotales()));
    }
    System.out.print(consulta);
 }
 
public static void comprarEntradaTeatro(Teatro miTeatro) {
     StringBuilder consulta = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        consulta.append(cabecera(String.format("Intentando comprar 1 entrada para la obra \"%s\" en el teatro \"%s\"", miTeatro.tieneObra() ? miTeatro.getObra() : "---", miTeatro.getNombreTeatro())) );
        miTeatro.comprarEntrada();
        consulta.append("Compra realizada con éxito.\n");
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        consulta.append(String.format("Error. %s\n", ex.getMessage()) );
    } finally {
        consulta.append(String.format("Número de entradas vendidas para la obra actual: %d\n", miTeatro.getEntradasVendidas()));
        consulta.append(String.format("Número de entradas vendidas totales: %d\n", Teatro.getEntradasVendidasTotales()));
    }
    System.out.print(consulta);
}
 

Y devolver entradas lo mismo.
```

Comment: He visto varias de tus publicaciones. A mí me parece que te estas enredando con tus variables (las que manejan las entradas). Debes tener solo dos: 1) Una que maneje el aforo máximo (la capacidad del teatro) y otra que te muestre la cantidad de entradas vendidas (un correlativo). La primera variable la seteas y NO la tocas más y es con la 2da con la que operas cuando vendes o devuelves entradas. La 2da variable nunca puede ser menor que cero y nunca mayor que la primera variable (la del aforo). En tu caso veo `Entradas `, `EntradasVendidas`,`EntradasVendidasTotales` y `AFORO_MAX`

Comment: Si @Yussef estoy liado y no encuentro la solución para hacer el ejercicio, no se porque no se ejecuta

Comment: Me gustaría ver la clase completa `Teatro`, es posible que la publique aquí o en otro lado?

Comment: Por otro lado, un tetro puede tener muchas obras asignadas?

Comment: @Yussef por aqui me corta, dice que pongo demasiado código. Por donde puedo mandártelo? email?

Comment: @Yussef un teatro puede tener una obra o ninguna obra asignada. si tiene obra se puede comprar entradas, si no, no

Comment: Podrías ponerlo acá https://www.online-java.com/ luego le das a F10 para compartir el código

Comment: @Yussef https://www.online-java.com/mLr4vGUgqz este es el enlace

Comment: Sigo intentando hacer cosas @Yussef pero estoy mas liado todavía tocando cosas que me hacen errar en otras cosas